# jquery range slider values which follows the handles?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm playing with jquery range slider, I've managed to split two values in different inputs. Now don't get mad at me, I'm still nooby about jquery and I was wondering how to set up that each input follow its handle on slider?

Like in this examples: http://egorkhmelev.github.io/jslider/

My code till now looks like this:

script:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".slider-assets" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 100,
        max: 500,
        values: [ 200, 300 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( ".amount-assets1" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + "k €");
            $( ".amount-assets2" ).val( ui.values[ 1 ] + "k €" );
        }
        });
        $( ".amount-assets1" ).val($( ".slider-assets" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + "k €" );
        $( ".amount-assets2" ).val($( ".slider-assets" ).slider( "values", 1 ) + "k €" );
});
```

html:

```
<input type="text" class="amount-assets1" />
<input type="text" class="amount-assets2" />
<div class="slider-assets"></div>
```

css:

```
.amount-assets1,.amount-assets2{
    width: 48px;
}
```

and you can see and play with my jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dzorz/sJBLh/

The problem is that I don't know from where to start. Do I need another one plugin that puts tooltip above handles or something else?

Any suggestion and solutions are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using the slider in the example you linked?

Comment: are you looking for this? [tooltip range for slider](http://css-tricks.com/value-bubbles-for-range-inputs/)

Comment: @Archer I wanna now how this tooltip was made...that is the only reason :)

Comment: @Ram that is quite good, I will try to implement it.. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to be specify your tool-tip handle with the event function
See the code:

```
var sliderTooltip = function(event, ui) {
var curValue = ui.value || initialValue;
var tooltip = '<div class="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-inner">' + curValue + '</div><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div></div>';

$('.ui-slider-handle').html(tooltip);
```

}

See below demo for complete reference:
http://jsfiddle.net/npsingh/WQe98/

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've managed to get it work: http://jsfiddle.net/dzorz/X3DVv/

little bit complicated in script but it works:

```
    $(function() {
    $( ".slider-assets" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 100,
        max: 500,
        values: [ 200, 300 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( ".amount-assets" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + "k € - " + ui.values[ 1 ] + "k €");

            $('.ui-slider-handle:first').html('<div class="tooltip top slider-tip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner">' + ui.values[0]  + "k €" + '</div></div>');
            $('.ui-slider-handle:last').html('<div class="tooltip top slider-tip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner">' + ui.values[1]  + "k €" + '</div></div>');

        }
        });
        $( ".amount-assets" ).val($( ".slider-assets" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + "k € - " + $( ".slider-assets" ).slider( "values", 1 ) + "k €" );

        $('.ui-slider-handle:first').html('<div class="tooltip top slider-tip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner">' + $(".slider-assets").slider("values", 0)  + "k €" + '</div></div>');
        $('.ui-slider-handle:last').html('<div class="tooltip top slider-tip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner">' + $(".slider-assets").slider("values", 1)  + "k €" + '</div></div>');
});
```